# How to compile from a github repository from Intellij in the build.gradle file?

Tags: android, git, github, intellij-idea

Let's pretend that I have a github repository at github.com/myprojects/myrepo

Let's also pretend that I have a project in IntelliJ with a build.gradle file that contains the following:

```
dependencies {
    // android
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    // google play services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

I want to add my github project via Gradle so I imagine that the dependencies need to add something like:

```
compile 'github.com:myprojects:myrepo'
```

This obviously isn't how it works though since I get "Failed to resolve com.github:myprojects:myrepo

Actual examples which work:

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:x.x.x'
```

Since I don't want to clone the repository into a libs folder, how can I add a compile command in the dependencies portion of my build.gradle file to compile from github so that I can simply add something like the following:

```
compile 'com.github.myprojects:myrepo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:x.x.x'

It works because this library is published in [Central Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar).

> compile 'github.com:myprojects:myrepo'
>
> This obviously isn't how it works though since I get "Failed to resolve >com.github:myprojects:myrepo

It is not enough to push on github.
You have to publish you artifact on Central Maven or JCenter or a local maven. You can find some guides to publish on jcenter, for example [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en).

Comment: Thank you. I personally could not get this to work (created bintray account ,set up repository, etc.) but I think this is how it's done so I'll mark as accepted. I might be able to figure it out eventually though. Cheers.